# Chess Game with GUI in C++ using SDL2

Tags: c++, game, c++11, chess, sdl2

### Introduction

So, I recently completed a chess game with a GUI in Python, using Pygame. Upon research, I learned that Pygame is built on SDL, and since I wanted to practice C++ more, I decided to code chess again in C++.

- I have 5 source files and 6 header files. Since this is a large project, feel free only to review the code design/style or just one file.

### Questions

- Is my use of `namespaces` correct?
- Is my header/source splitting (organization) correct? I come from Python so don't have too much experience
- Is SDL2 used properly? (eg. is there a better way to handle events, draw the board...)
- Is my game logic correct? (eg. a better way to check bishop moves, pawn moves...)
- Is my piece/board representation good?
- Are there missed optimizations/shortcuts?
- Generally, is this idiomatic C++?

### Project Info

This project was compiled with `g++` on a Late 2012 MacBookPro.

#### Compiler flags

- -I $(INCLUDE_DIR)
- -Wall
- -Wextra
- -std=c++11

#### Linker flags

- -D_THREAD_SAFE
- -lSDL2
- -lSDL2_image
- -lSDL2_ttf (not used but planning to use)

### Code

**board.cpp**

```
#include "board.hpp"

#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "defines.hpp"
#include "game.hpp"
#include "pieces.hpp"

// TODO: add other FEN fields
void Board::readFen(std::string fen) {
    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;

    for (char c : fen) {
        if (c == '/') {
            row++;
            col = 0;
            continue;
        } else {
            if (isdigit(c)) {
                for (int _ = 0; _ < static_cast<int>(c - '0'); _++) {
                    this->board[row][col] = 0x00;
                    col++;
                }
            } else {
                PieceColor color = isupper(c) ? WHITE : BLACK;
                Piece p;

                c = tolower(c);

                switch (c) {
                    case 'p':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(PAWN, color);
                        break;
                    case 'r':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(ROOK, color);
                        break;
                    case 'n':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(KNIGHT, color);
                        break;
                    case 'b':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(BISHOP, color);
                        break;
                    case 'q':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(QUEEN, color);
                        break;
                    case 'k':
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(KING, color);
                        break;
                    default:
                        p = Pieces::makePiece(PAWN, color);
                }

                this->board[row][col] = p;
                col++;
            }
        }
    }
}
// TODO: add other info to board printing
void Board::printBoard() {
    std::cout << "CHESSBOARD INFO" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Turn: " << (this->getActiveColor() == WHITE ? "white" : "black") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Move: " << this->getMoveNumber() << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            std::cout << this->board[i][j] << std::string((board[i][j] >= 10 ? 1 : 2), ' ');
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

PieceColor Board::getActiveColor() {
    return this->active_color;
}

float Board::getMoveNumber() {
    return this->move_number;
}

void Board::incrementMoveNumber() {
    this->move_number += 0.5f;
}

void Board::toggleActiveColor() {
    this->active_color = this->getActiveColor() == WHITE ? BLACK : WHITE;
}

void Board::reverse() {
    int board[8][8];

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            board[7 - i][j] = this->board[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            this->board[i][j] = board[i][j];
        }
    }

    this->is_reversed = !this->is_reversed;
}

bool Board::isReversed() {
    return this->is_reversed;
}

void Board::tryMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    if (this->getActiveColor() != Pieces::getPieceColor(this->getPieceAt(starting))) { // out of turn
        return;
    }

    if (Game::isValidMove(this, starting, ending, true)) {
        this->makeMove(starting, ending);
        this->clearSelectedPiece();

        this->incrementMoveNumber();
        this->toggleActiveColor();
    }
}

void Board::makeMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    int r1, c1, r2, c2;

    r1 = starting.first;
    c1 = starting.second;

    r2 = ending.first;
    c2 = ending.second;

    this->board[r2][c2] = this->board[r1][c1];
    this->board[r1][c1] = 0x00;
}

int Board::getPieceAt(Location location) {
    return this->board[location.first][location.second];
}


Location Board::getSelectedPiece() {
    return this->selected_piece;
}

void Board::setSelectedPiece(int i, int j) {
    this->selected_piece = makeLocation(i, j);
}

void Board::clearSelectedPiece() {
    this->selected_piece = makeLocation(-1, -1);
}

bool Board::hasSelectedPiece() {
    return (this->selected_piece.first != -1 && this->selected_piece.second != -1);
}
```

**game.cpp**

```
#include "game.hpp"

#include <iostream>

#include "board.hpp"
#include "defines.hpp"
#include "pieces.hpp"


bool Game::isValidMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, bool check_king) {
    Piece starting_piece = board->getPieceAt(starting);
    Piece ending_piece = board->getPieceAt(ending);

    PieceColor starting_color = Pieces::getPieceColor(starting_piece);

    if (ending_piece != 0x00 && starting_color == Pieces::getPieceColor(ending_piece)) {
        return false;  // can't capture your own piece
    }

    bool result = true;
    switch (Pieces::getPieceClass(starting_piece)) {
        case PAWN:
            result = isValidPawnMove(board, starting, ending, starting_color);
            break;
        case KNIGHT:
            result = isValidKnightMove(starting, ending);
            break;
        case BISHOP:
            result = isValidBishopMove(board, starting, ending, starting_color);
            break;
        case ROOK:
            result = isValidRookMove(board, starting, ending, starting_color);
            break;
        case QUEEN:
            result = isValidQueenMove(board, starting, ending, starting_color);
            break;
        case KING:
            result = isValidKingMove(starting, ending);
            break;
    }

    if (!check_king) {
        return result;
    } else if (result == false) {
        return result;
    }

    board->makeMove(starting, ending);

    if (isInCheck(board, starting_color)) {
        board->makeMove(ending, starting);
        board->board[ending.first][ending.second] = ending_piece;
        return false;
    }

    board->makeMove(ending, starting);
    board->board[ending.first][ending.second] = ending_piece;
    return true;
}

bool Game::isValidPawnMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color) {
    Piece ending_piece = board->getPieceAt(ending);

    PieceColor opposite_color = starting_color == WHITE ? BLACK : WHITE;

    if (!board->isReversed()) {
        opposite_color = starting_color;
    }
    if (ending_piece == 0) {  // open piece
        if (opposite_color == WHITE) {
            if (
                starting.first == 6 && starting.first - ending.first == 2 && starting.second == ending.second) {
                return true;
            }
            if (
                starting.first - ending.first == 1 && starting.second == ending.second) {
                return true;
            }
        } else if (opposite_color == BLACK) {
            if (
                starting.first == 1 && ending.first - starting.first == 2 && starting.second == ending.second) {
                return true;
            }
            if (
                ending.first - starting.first == 1 && starting.second == ending.second) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {  // piece is occupied
        if (starting_color == WHITE) {
            if (ending.first == starting.first - 1) {
                if (abs(ending.second - starting.second) == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else if (starting_color == BLACK) {
            if (ending.first == starting.first + 1) {
                if (abs(ending.second - starting.second) == 1) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

bool Game::isValidKnightMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    int x_diff = abs(ending.first - starting.first);
    int y_diff = abs(ending.second - starting.second);

    if (x_diff == 1 && y_diff == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    if (x_diff == 2 && y_diff == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Game::isValidBishopMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color) {
    if (starting.first + starting.second != ending.first + ending.second && starting.first - starting.second != ending.first - ending.second) {
        return false;
    }

    int x_change = ending.second < starting.second ? -1 : 1;
    int y_change = ending.first < starting.first ? -1 : 1;

    Location indices = starting;

    while (0 <= indices.first <= 7 && 0 <= indices.second <= 7 && indices != ending) {
        indices.second += x_change;
        indices.first += y_change;

        if (board->getPieceAt(indices)) {
            if (Pieces::getPieceColor(board->getPieceAt(indices)) == starting_color) {
                indices.second -= x_change;
                indices.first -= y_change;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    if (indices == ending) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Game::isValidRookMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color) {
    if (
        starting.first != ending.first && starting.second != ending.second) {
        return false;
    }

    int x_change, y_change;

    x_change = ending.second < starting.second ? -1 : 1;
    y_change = ending.first < starting.first ? -1 : 1;

    x_change = ending.second == starting.second ? 0 : x_change;
    y_change = ending.first == starting.first ? 0 : y_change;

    Location indices = (starting);

    while (0 <= indices.first <= 7 && 0 <= indices.second <= 7 && indices != ending) {
        indices.second += x_change;
        indices.first += y_change;

        if (board->getPieceAt(indices)) {
            if (Pieces::getPieceColor(board->getPieceAt(indices)) == starting_color) {
                indices.second -= x_change;
                indices.first -= y_change;
            }

            break;
        }
    }
    if (indices == ending) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Game::isValidQueenMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color) {
    return isValidBishopMove(
               board, starting, ending, starting_color) ||
           isValidRookMove(board, starting, ending, starting_color);
}

bool Game::isValidKingMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    int x_diff = abs(starting.first - ending.first);
    int y_diff = abs(starting.second - ending.second);

    if (x_diff == 1 and y_diff == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    if (x_diff == 1 and y_diff == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (x_diff == 0 and y_diff == 1) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Game::isInCheck(Board* board, PieceColor color) {
    Location king_location;
    Piece piece;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            piece = board->getPieceAt(makeLocation(i, j));
            if (Pieces::getPieceClass(piece) == KING && Pieces::getPieceColor(piece) == color) {
                king_location = makeLocation(i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            piece = board->getPieceAt(makeLocation(i, j));
            if (piece == 0x00) {
                continue;
            }

            if (Pieces::getPieceColor(piece) != color) {
                if (Game::isValidMove(board, makeLocation(i, j), king_location, false)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool Game::isInCheckMate(Board* board, PieceColor color) {
    Location king_location;
    Piece piece;

    if (!isInCheck(board, color)) {
        return false;  // can't be in mate if ur not checked
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            piece = board->getPieceAt(makeLocation(i, j));
            if (Pieces::getPieceClass(piece) == KING && Pieces::getPieceColor(piece) == color) {
                king_location = makeLocation(i, j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            piece = board->getPieceAt(makeLocation(i, j));
            if (piece == 0x00) {
                continue;
            }

            if (Pieces::getPieceColor(piece) == color) {
                Location starting_location = makeLocation(i, j);
                Location ending_location;

                for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                        ending_location = makeLocation(x, y);

                        if (Game::isValidMove(board, starting_location, ending_location, true)) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**gui.cpp**

```
#include "gui.hpp"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "board.hpp"
#include "defines.hpp"
#include "game.hpp"
#include "pieces.hpp"

// TODO: add special moves like castle, en passant
// TODO: add showing checkmate

void GUI::initSDL() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
}

void GUI::cleanupSDL(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Window* window) {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

SDL_Window* GUI::createSDLWindow() {
    return SDL_CreateWindow("C++ Chess", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                            WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
}

SDL_Renderer* GUI::createSDLRenderer(SDL_Window* window) {
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "2");
    return SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
}

void GUI::drawChessboard(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Board* board) {
    Piece p;
    Location selected_piece = board->getSelectedPiece();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            SDL_Rect tile;

            tile.x = j * TILE_SIZE;
            tile.y = i * TILE_SIZE;
            tile.w = TILE_SIZE;
            tile.h = TILE_SIZE;

            if ((i + j) % 2 == (board->isReversed() ? 1 : 0)) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xFF);
            } else {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0xFF);
            }

            if (selected_piece.first == i && selected_piece.second == j) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);

                SDL_Rect highlight;
                highlight.x = tile.x + 5;
                highlight.y = tile.y + 3;
                highlight.w = tile.w - 10;
                highlight.h = tile.h - 10;

                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &tile);

                if ((i + j) % 2 == (board->isReversed() ? 1 : 0)) {
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xFF);
                } else {
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x99, 0x99, 0x99, 0xFF);
                }

                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &highlight);
            } else {
                SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &tile);
            }

            p = board->board[i][j];

            if (p != 0) {
                std::string filepath = "../data/bmp/" + Pieces::getPieceFilename(p);

                SDL_Surface* image = SDL_LoadBMP(filepath.c_str());
                if (image == NULL) {
                    std::cerr << "image=" << image << " Reason: " << SDL_GetError() << " " << SDL_GetBasePath() << std::endl;
                }
                SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, image);

                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, &tile);

                SDL_FreeSurface(image);
                SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
            }

            if (board->hasSelectedPiece() && Game::isValidMove(board, board->getSelectedPiece(), makeLocation(i, j), true)) {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF);

                int centerX = tile.x + tile.w / 2;
                int centerY = tile.y + tile.h / 2;
                int radius = 15;
                SDL_RenderFillCircle(renderer, centerX, centerY, radius);
            }
        }
    }
}

int GUI::SDL_RenderFillCircle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, int radius) {
    int offsetx, offsety, d;
    int status;

    offsetx = 0;
    offsety = radius;
    d = radius - 1;
    status = 0;

    while (offsety >= offsetx) {
        status += SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x - offsety, y + offsetx,
                                     x + offsety, y + offsetx);
        status += SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x - offsetx, y + offsety,
                                     x + offsetx, y + offsety);
        status += SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x - offsetx, y - offsety,
                                     x + offsetx, y - offsety);
        status += SDL_RenderDrawLine(renderer, x - offsety, y - offsetx,
                                     x + offsety, y - offsetx);

        if (status < 0) {
            status = -1;
            break;
        }

        if (d >= 2 * offsetx) {
            d -= 2 * offsetx + 1;
            offsetx += 1;
        } else if (d < 2 * (radius - offsety)) {
            d += 2 * offsety - 1;
            offsety -= 1;
        } else {
            d += 2 * (offsety - offsetx - 1);
            offsety -= 1;
            offsetx += 1;
        }
    }

    return status;
}

void GUI::handleMouseClicked(SDL_MouseButtonEvent event, Board* board) {
    if (event.button == SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) {
        return;
    }

    Location board_indices = getBoardIndices(event.x, event.y);

    if (board->getSelectedPiece() == board_indices) {  // de-select a piece
        board->clearSelectedPiece();
    } else if (!board->hasSelectedPiece()) {  // select a piece
        if (board->getPieceAt(board_indices) != 0 && Pieces::getPieceColor(board->getPieceAt(board_indices)) == board->getActiveColor()) {
            board->setSelectedPiece(board_indices.first, board_indices.second);
        }
    } else if (board->hasSelectedPiece()) {  // move a piece
        if (Pieces::getPieceColor(board->getPieceAt(board_indices)) == Pieces::getPieceColor(board->getPieceAt(board->getSelectedPiece()))) {
            board->setSelectedPiece(board_indices.first, board_indices.second);
        } else {
            board->tryMove(board->getSelectedPiece(), board_indices);
        }
    }
}

void GUI::handleKeyPressed(SDL_KeyboardEvent event, Board* board) {
    if (event.keysym.sym == SDL_GetKeyFromName("r") || event.keysym.sym == SDL_GetKeyFromName("f")) {
        std::cout << "r/f pressed, reversing board" << std::endl;
        board->reverse();
    }
}

Location GUI::getBoardIndices(int x, int y) {
    /**
     * Gets board indices from a x, y coordinate of a mouse click.
     *
     * @param x: integer value of x coordiate of mouse click
     * @param y: integer value of y coordiate of mouse click
     *
     * @returns std::pair with integer values from 0-7 in first and second
     */

    Location out;

    out.second = x / TILE_SIZE;
    out.first = y / TILE_SIZE;

    return out;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "main.hpp"

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include <iostream>

#include "board.hpp"
#include "game.hpp"
#include "gui.hpp"

int main() {
    SDL_Window* window = GUI::createSDLWindow();
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = GUI::createSDLRenderer(window);

    SDL_Event event;

    Board board;

    board.readFen(STARTING_FEN);
    board.printBoard();

    bool running = true;
    bool gameover = false;

    while (running) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                running = false;
            } else if (event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP && !gameover) {
                GUI::handleMouseClicked(event.button, &board);
            } else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP && !gameover) {
                GUI::handleKeyPressed(event.key, &board);
            }
        }

        if (gameover) {
            continue;
        }

        if (Game::isInCheckMate(&board, WHITE)) {
            std::cout << "WHITE IS MATED" << std::endl;
            gameover = true;
        }
        if (Game::isInCheckMate(&board, BLACK)) {
            std::cout << "BLACK IS MATED" << std::endl;
            gameover = true;
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        GUI::drawChessboard(renderer, &board);

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }

    GUI::cleanupSDL(renderer, window);

    return 0;
}
```

**pieces.cpp**

```
#include "pieces.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

PieceColor Pieces::getPieceColor(Piece p) {
    int color = p >> 3;

    if (color == 1) {
        return BLACK;
    } else if (color == 2) {
        return WHITE;
    } else {
        return NOCOLOR;
    }
}

PieceClass Pieces::getPieceClass(Piece p) {
    int pc = p & 7;

    return static_cast<PieceEnum>(pc);
}

std::string Pieces::getPieceFilename(Piece p) {
    PieceColor color = getPieceColor(p);
    PieceClass pc = getPieceClass(p);

    std::string filename;

    switch (color) {
        case WHITE:
            filename += "white_";
            break;
        case BLACK:
            filename += "black_";
            break;
    }

    switch (pc) {
        case PAWN:
            filename += "pawn";
            break;
        case KNIGHT:
            filename += "knight";
            break;
        case BISHOP:
            filename += "bishop";
            break;
        case ROOK:
            filename += "rook";
            break;
        case QUEEN:
            filename += "queen";
            break;
        case KING:
            filename += "king";
            break;
    }

    filename += ".bmp";

    return filename;
}

Piece Pieces::makePiece(PieceClass c, PieceColor pc) {
    return c | pc;
}
```

### Headers

**board.hpp**

```
#ifndef BOARD_H_INCLUDED
#define BOARD_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include "defines.hpp"
#include "pieces.hpp"

const std::string STARTING_FEN = "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR";

class Board {
   private:
    PieceColor active_color = WHITE;
    float move_number = 1.0f;

    bool is_reversed = false;

    Location selected_piece = {-1, -1};

   public:
    int board[8][8];

    float getMoveNumber();
    void incrementMoveNumber();

    PieceColor getActiveColor();
    void toggleActiveColor();

    Location getSelectedPiece();
    int getPieceAt(Location location);

    void setSelectedPiece(int i, int j);
    bool hasSelectedPiece();
    void clearSelectedPiece();


    void tryMove(Location starting, Location ending);
    void makeMove(Location starting, Location ending);


    void readFen(std::string fen);
    void printBoard();

    void reverse();
    bool isReversed();
};

#endif  // !BOARD_H_INCLUDED
```

**defines.hpp**

```
#ifndef DEFINES_HPP_INCLUDED
#define DEFINES_HPP_INCLUDED

typedef std::pair<int, int> Location;

inline std::pair<int, int> makeLocation(int i, int j) {
    return std::make_pair(i, j);
}

#endif // !DEFINES_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**game.hpp**

```
#ifndef GAME_HPP_INCLUDED
#define GAME_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "board.hpp"
#include "pieces.hpp"

namespace Game {
bool isValidMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, bool check_king);

bool isValidPawnMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color);
bool isValidKnightMove(Location starting, Location ending);
bool isValidBishopMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color);
bool isValidRookMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color);
bool isValidQueenMove(Board* board, Location starting, Location ending, PieceColor starting_color);
bool isValidKingMove(Location starting, Location ending);

bool isInCheck(Board* board, PieceColor color);
bool isInCheckMate(Board* board, PieceColor color);
}  // namespace Game

#endif  // !GAME_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**gui.hpp**

```
#ifndef GUI_H_INCLUDED
#define GUI_H_INCLUDED

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#include "board.hpp"

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1200;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1200;

const int TILE_SIZE = 150;

namespace GUI {
    void initSDL();
    void cleanupSDL(SDL_Renderer* renderer, SDL_Window* window);

    SDL_Window* createSDLWindow();
    SDL_Renderer* createSDLRenderer(SDL_Window* window);

    void drawChessboard(SDL_Renderer* renderer, Board* board);
    int SDL_RenderFillCircle(SDL_Renderer* renderer, int x, int y, int radius);

    void handleMouseClicked(SDL_MouseButtonEvent event, Board* board);
    void handleKeyPressed(SDL_KeyboardEvent event, Board* board);

    std::pair<int, int> getBoardIndices(int x, int y);

}  // namespace GUI

#endif  // !GUI_H_INCLUDED
```

**main.hpp**

```
#ifndef MAIN_HPP_INCLUDED
#define MAIN_HPP_INCLUDED

// TODO: add stuff or remove if unnessecary

#endif // !MAIN_HPP_INCLUDED
```

**pieces.hpp**

```
#ifndef PIECES_H_INCLUDED
#define PIECES_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

typedef unsigned int Piece;
typedef unsigned int PieceColor;
typedef unsigned int PieceClass;

enum PieceColors {
    WHITE = 16,
    BLACK = 8,
    NOCOLOR = 0
};

enum PieceEnum {
    PAWN,
    KNIGHT,
    BISHOP,
    ROOK,
    QUEEN,
    KING
};

namespace Pieces {
    PieceColor getPieceColor(Piece p);
    PieceClass getPieceClass(Piece p);
    Piece makePiece(PieceClass c, PieceColor pc);
    std::string getPieceFilename(Piece p);
}  // namespace Pieces

#endif  // !PIECES_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're already on C++11, it shouldn't be too much effort to move to C++17 or 20, which you should pursue.

Since you have a project with multiple translation units (object files), strongly consider:

- enable `-flto`, link-time optimization
- enable `-fvisibility=hidden`

`readFen` should not accept a `std::string`, but instead a `const std::string &`.

Don't use `_` as an iteration variable (don't do this in Python either; it isn't unused).

This is a matter of personal taste, but I prefer to omit `this->` when there is an unambiguous member name.

`printBoard` should be `printBoard() const`. The same for every one of your `get` methods and `isValidMove`. When possible, these should also be given the `constexpr` prefix.

This is also (mostly) a matter of personal preference, but for simple one-line accessors like `getActiveColor`, just define them in the header and not separately in the `.cpp`.

`isValidBishopMove` and the like should accept a `const Board &`, not a `Board*`.

`std::string filepath` can be replaced with the new STL `filesystem::path` library.

`Board::board` must not be `public`.

Almost all `isValidMove` and family can just be methods on `Board`, since they need a `Board` reference anyway.

Replace your `enum`s with `enum class`.

There's more, but that's a start.

Answer (score 4):

## Answers to your questions

> - Is my use of namespaces correct?

It's definitely better than not using namespaces. However, you can improve it:

- Move more things into the namespaces. For example, why not move `WINDOW_WIDTH`, `WINDOW_HEIGHT` and `TILE_SIZE` into `namespace GUI`?
  Similarly for `PieceColors` and `PieceEnum`, these could be moved into `Pieces`.
- A `class` is effectively also a namespace. Instead of having a `namespace Game` which just contains functions for checking valid moves, many of which take a `Board*` as the first parameter, why not move these functions into `class Board`?

> - Is my header/source splitting (organization) correct? I come from Python so don't have too much experience

It is correct. Be aware when [defining](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) variables inside header files though, for example `STARTING_FEN` in `board.hpp`. If multiple source files include that, they would each cause a new variable to be defined, but since they have the same name in the global namespace, this can lead to a conflict at link time. Here it is fine because `STARTING_FEN` is `const` and since this is C++, but without `const` this wouldn't compile. If you are aware of this, it is fine.

Note that if you have non-`const` variables you want to *define* in header files, you can make the [`inline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) since C++17.

> - Is SDL2 used properly? (eg. is there a better way to handle events, draw the board...)

Using `SDL_Renderer` is great for 2D programs. You enabled VSYNC which is also great. However, if most of the time nothing changes on screen, you can avoid even that. Use `SDL_WaitEvent()` to wait for something to happen.

You also have fixed the size of the window. Consider that someone might want to resize it, for example if they have a much larger or smaller screen than what you assume. Set the `SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE` flag when creating the `SDL_Window`. The nice thing about `SDL_Renderer` is that the rendering surface can have a different size than the window has, and SDL will take care of scaling if necessary.

> - Is my game logic correct? (eg. a better way to check bishop moves, pawn moves...)

Be aware that C++ handles expressions like `a < b < c` differently than Python does. While Python handles this the way you'd expect this from mathematics, in C++ it evaluates the first comparison first, which yields a boolean true or false value, and then that boolean is compared to the third value. So `0 <= indices.first <= 7` will always be `true`, because `0 <= indices.first` will be `true` or `false`, but `true` (1) and `false` (0) will always be considered less than 7. You have to write it in the form `a < b && b < c`:

```
while (0 <= indices.first && indices.first <= 7 &&
       0 <= indices.second && indices.second <= 7 &&
       indices != ending) {
    …
}
```

I also recommend you make more helper functions to simplify the code. For example, in `isValidBishopMove()`, the very first `if`-statement should be replaced with something that looks like:

```
if (!isDiagonalMove(starting, ending)) {
    return false;
}
```

> - Is my piece/board representation good?

Using a two-dimensional array makes sense. However, avoid using `int` as the type for things that are not actually integer numbers. Since a board is made up of 8 by 8 squares, create a struct named `Square`, so you can write:

```
Square board[8][8];
```

And `Square` should describe what is on a given square, so for example:

```
struct Square {
    enum Color: std::uint8_t {
        NONE,
        WHITE,
        BLACK,
    } color;

    enum Piece: std::uint8_t {
        PAWN,
        KNIGHT,
        …,
    } piece;
};
```

In the above, I gave each [`enum`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) an explicit type, so the struct only takes 2 bytes, as opposed to `int` being 4 bytes on most platforms.
However, there are many [other ways](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2831) to represent chess boards, with various tradeoffs in complexity and performance.

Use enums where possible, and don't fall back to `int`. Statements like `if (piece == 0x00)` should not appear in your code.

> - Are there missed optimizations/shortcuts?

For a simple GUI for playing chess, without a computer AI, this looks fine. I don't think you should worry about performance here. Focus on making the code more readable.

> - Generally, is this idiomatic C++?

It doesn't look too bad. Some things that can be improved are:

- Avoid writing `this->`, it's almost never necessary in C++. If you tend to give local variables in member functions the same name as class member variables, consider renaming either the local variable, or add a prefix like `m_` to member variables. The latter is a common code style.
- [Don't use `std::endl`, write `'\n'`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n)
- Pass by (`const`) reference instead of by pointer where possible.
- Use [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for constants where possible.

## Use `std::` also for C functions

If you include the C header files using `#include <csomething>` instead of `#include <something.h>`, which you indeed should, make sure you prepend `std::` to the functions and variables you use from those header files. While often it will work without, it is not guaranteed by the C++ standard that the C functions will be available in the global namespace.

For math functions, using the `std::` version has the additional benefit of automatically selecting the right version depending on the type of the argument; for example if you would pass a `long` to `abs()` it would be silently truncated to an `int`, but [`std::abs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs) will do the right thing.

## Carefully read the documentation of the `<cctype>` functions

The functions from the `<cctype>` header do not work on `char`s, but on `int`s, and they handle negative values differently than expected. For 7-bit ASCII characters it's not a problem, but if you have high ASCII characters or UTF-8 characters, `char`s might have negative values, and this causes issues. Make sure you cast to `unsigned char` before you pass characters to functions like [`std::isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

## Prefer a `struct` over a `std::pair`

There are certainly cases where you want to use a `std::pair` or `std::tuple`, but if you can define a `struct` instead, prefer that. You can give struct members useful names, whereas `std::pair` forces you to use `.first` and `.second`, and then you have to remember the order of things. So instead of making `Location` an alias for a `std::pair<int, int>`, write:

```
struct Location {
    int row;
    int col;
};
```

You also don't need a `makeLocation()` function, you can just write:

```
piece = getPieceAt({i, j});
```

## Make more use of the types you define

It's very good to create a type like `Location` instead of passing two `int`s everywhere. However, you could use `Location` in more places. For example, you can define a member function that takes a `Location` as an argument, and returns a *reference* to an element of `board[][]`:

```
Square& Board::squareAt(Location postion) {
    return board[position.row][position.col];
};
```

That will simplify other functions, for example:

```
void Board::makeMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    squareAt(ending) = squareAt(starting);
    squareAt(starting) = {};
}
```

You could also overload math operators and write your own `abs()` function that takes `Location`. That way you could write:

```
bool Game::isValidKingMove(Location starting, Location ending) {
    Location abs_diff = abs(starting - ending);
    return (abs_diff.row | abs_diff.col) == 1;
}
```

Comment: You can use the SDL2 library with smart pointers. Unfortunately I can't find the origional post on this site, that demonstrated this so well, but [this SO question pretty much sums it up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990404/smart-pointers-in-sdl-wrapper-header). Google "_wrappers for sdl2 pointers C++_ " and there's lots of info (now). Also using **std::**, you can get your text editor/IDE to prepend **std::** automatically for you, save some typing.

Comment: [I did find this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129389/pong-game-with-a-random-twist), which uses smart_pointers for SDL2 raw pointers, which looks pretty good.